# Google Calender API: Possible to store events in own private calendar?

Tags: google-calendar-api

I am currently writing an online-booking-module and I want to store events (beside in the database) in a owned google-calendar (this calendar is then added to the responsible employee in outlook).

**My idea was just to give the API my auth-data and the calendar-id and then being able to insert and delete events.**

The calendar must be private, not public!

Now I see it is more designed to access user's calenders getting their permission etc...

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer:

*Yes, you can authenticate the application as yourself and add the events to a private calendar owned by you.*

#### More Information:

Once the application has been published and contains your credentials and token, there will be no issue running the Events add Calendar API method as you, regardless of who runs the program.

#### Other option:

Alternatively, you could create a Service account to impersonate your account and run the calendar API queries, though you would need to provide the Service Account with access to your private Google Calendar.

#### References:

- [Google Calendar API - `Events: insert`](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/insert)
- [Authorizing Requests to the Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/auth)
- [Google Developer Admin Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/dashboard)
- [Google Cloud - Service Accounts](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts)
- [Understanding Service Accounts](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts)
- [Creating and Managing Service Accounts](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts)
- [Creating and Managing Service Account Keys](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys#iam-service-account-keys-create-python)
- [Granting Roles to Service Accounts](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-changing-revoking-access)